# Плохо работает график на canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Вот такой код графика: https://jsfiddle.net/0vLweqyn/2/ ,все работает.

Но увеличив числа в массиве ( и даже сменив `count`) все прибилось к полу,как это можно исправить? https://jsfiddle.net/tf0a5xzk/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что это за чепуха?

```
  var maxCount = 5411 + 6293;
  var stepY = Math.round(height / maxCount);
```

Уберите, по крайней мере, `Math.round`.

Comment: Я брал этот исходник с другого урока,сам в canvas не шарю

Comment: @IvanZ "в ... не шарю" - не является уважительной причиной. Вы взялись программировать - шарьте.

Comment: Я не собираюсь учить что-либо ненужное мне. Я не попросил кого-либо написать мне что-то с нуля,я попросил помочь найти ошибку,что и делают тут. Что-то не так?

Comment: @IvanZ Я уже написал, что не так. Если это Вам не нужно, зачем же Вы об этом спрашиваете?

Comment: Понял,спасибо за ответ и советы,только единственное,что слева текст поплыл.

Comment: @IvanZ "Точность - вежливость программистов." Что значит "текст поплыл"?

Comment: Текст,расположенный в левой части экрана,обозначающий значения,пересекается с другими текстами,образуя раздвоенные тексты. Как это можно пофиксить?

Comment: @IvanZ Очень хорошо. Какой смысл Вы вкладываете в слово "пофиксить"? Как это должно выглядеть, когда метки на оси налезают друг на друга?

Comment: Что-то вроде поведения тегов div,т.е чтобы они не накладывались,а располагались с небольшим отступом друг от друга,или просто убирать те которые наехали

Comment: @IvanZ Волшебства не будет :). Вам надо будет запоминать прямоугольники с отрисоваными значениями и пропускать/сдвигать те метки, которые пересекаются с этим списком.

Comment: Немного не понял что нужно сделать.